# How to get select rights of information_schema.schemata in grrenplum

Tags: greenplum

I created a new user in greenplum db and just want to give select rights of  information_schema.schemata table. After running below query I am just able to select the information_schema.schemata table with out eror however no data appears.

```
GRANT SELECT ON information_schema.schemata TO <username>;

GRANT SELECT ON information_schema.schemata TO <username>;
SELECT * FROM information_schema.schemata ;
```

I am expecting the data should be shown to me from new user however I am getting below message with no data.

```
Total query runtime: 291 msec
0 rows retrieved.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no problems running this on version 5.x of GP but got the same results as you on GP 4.3.32.1 (the latest 4.3 release). 
Looking at the definition of the information_schema.schemata view

```
\d+ information_schema.schemata
```

shows that is joins two tables, pg_namespace and pg_authid, from the pg_catalog schema.
In 4.3.x, a regular user doesn't have access to pg_authid.
So, as gpadmin, run:

```
psql -d <userdb> -c 'grant select on pg_catalog.pg_authid to <user>'
```

Then your query should work.

Comment: It is working fine however one schema is not coming in the query after giving full schema rights to new user.GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA name TO <username>;

Comment: You should not need to grant anything to tables in a view, just SELECT to the view itself.